# PHP/Laravel: create JSON with a particular Key name

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I am using imagick to get a number of pages and save it to json. 
But I store the number as is: for example - 20.
I need to store the number with a key like this:

```
    {
       "pages": "20"
    }
```

Here is the code example, that I have. `$json` - just a path to a created json file. `$num`  - number of pages.

```
 Storage::put(($json), $num);
```

Should I creat json first, and then somehow add key to a number and encode file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /**
     * Write the contents of a file.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string|resource $contents
     * @param mixed $options
     * @return bool 
     * @static 
     */ 
    public static function put($path, $contents, $options = array())
    {
        return \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::put($path, $contents, $options);
    }
```

The second parameter to `Storage::put` is the raw contents you wish to store in the given path. So yes, you have to encode your metadata in your desired format first.

E.g.:

```
$data = ['pages' => $num];
Storage::put($jsonPath, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: and then if I want to add in another function the second key with an array? smth like: `{"files":"20", "map": { "key": "value", etc.}}` using PHP. Where can I find info about working with json's ?

Comment: Simply add more entries to the `$data` array before passing it to `json_encode()`. E.g.: `$data = ['files' => 20, 'map' => ['key => 'value', 'etc' => '...']]`